# Удалить из строки все до первого пробела, включая сам пробел

Tags: строки, visual-c++

Имеется введенная строка `58 3` из неё нужно удалить все, чтобы осталось только число `3`. Как это реализовать?

Имеется цикл, позволяющий удалить все, что есть после пробела:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= z; i++)
    {
        if (cstr[i] == ' ')
        {
            cnt++;
            for (int j = i; j < z - 1; ++j)
            {
                cstr[z - cnt] = '\0';
            }           
        }
    }
```

Как изменить его так, чтобы он удалял все, что до пробела и сам пробел?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с использованием `std::string`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "foo bar";

    std::size_t pos = s1.find(" ");
    if (pos != std::string::npos) 
    {
        s1.erase(0, pos+1);
        std::cout << s1 << std::endl; // bar
    }       
    else
    {
        std::cout << "В исходной строке нет пробелов" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вариант с Си-строками

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[] = "foo bar";

    char *s2 = strchr(s1, ' '); // находим указатель на первое вхождение символа в строке

    if(s2 != NULL)
    {
        s2++; // переходим к следующему символу
        std::cout << s2 << std::endl; // bar
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "В исходной строке нет пробелов" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```